# How to disable typescript check for whole project in an Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to disable the type check for whole project and my for my use case I cannot use commands meant for disabling it for each file/line like // @ts-nocheck etc.

It will be better If I can use some config option that can be added in tsconfig.json

I tried below options but none of them worked

```
"compilerOptions": {
"noImplicitAny": false,
"strict": false,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"checkJs": false,
}

"linteroptions": {
"exclude": \["src/\*\*"\],
}

"angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
"strictInjectionParameters": false,
"strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
"strictTemplates": false
},
```

Comment: Are you asking about IDE analysis or are you saying that you want a command to specify specific files for type checking?

Comment: Not about IDE I just need to disable type checking for whole TS project